# How to compare hours in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a simple script to check if the current hour is before or after 12:00 AM.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=`date +"%T"` # error "not an integer"
var2='12:00:00'
if [ $var1 -lt $var2 ]; then # always false
    echo "Good morning!"
else
    echo "Good afternoon!"
fi
```

The error says that var1 must be an integer number, and the condition is always false.
I would like some help please. Thank you very much.

Comment: Suggestion: `var1=$(date + "%T")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test you are using can only compare integer numbers.
`date +%T` produces strings containing `:`, so your test fails.

You could use `date +%H` and set `var2=12`.

Or you could use `date +%H%M%S` and set `var2=120000`.

That being said, I'd suggest you use `$(date ...)` instead of the backticks.  It's much easier to read and allows you to wrap multiple commands into one.